# Do exists such linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Do exists such linear transformation :

$F:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 F(1, 2, 1) = (1, 0, 0), F(1, 0, 1) = (0, 1, 0), F(0, 1, 0) = (1, 0, 0)$

How should I do it in general?

Comment: You can define a linear transformation in any way you like on any *basis* and extend it to the rest of the space. Is your set of input vectors a basis?

Comment: @pjs36 True, but the OP is asking about linearity of $F$. This doesn’t require knowing all of $F$. In fact, the crux of the exercise appears to be noticing that the input vectors *are* linearly dependent.

Comment: @amd Indeed, I was hoping OP would get to discover that crux for themselves, while being nudged in a productive direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = (1,2,1)$, $b=(1,0,1)$ and $c=(0,1,0)$.  Then notice that $F(a)$ should equal $F(b+2c)$.  But it doesn't.  So the answer is "no such linear transformation exists."  To do it in general, write $a, b,$ and $c$ as rows of a matrix $A$ and solve each $Ax = v_i$, where the $v_i$ are in vectors you want to hit in the codomain.